# Is there some way how to shutdown tokio::runtime::Runtime?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

Problem is in a microservice with Tokio, where connect to db and other stuff async, but when some connection failed, microservice dont end work. Its a great when you need this case, but I need to end work of this microservice when connection lost... so could you help me how to safety shutdown process...?

```
src/main.rs

use tokio; // 1.0.0+

fn main() {
    let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .worker_threads(workers_number)
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    rt.block_on(async {
    // health cheacker connection
    let health_checker = match HealthChecker::new(some_configuration).await?;
    // some connection to db
    // ...
    // transport client connection
    // ...

    // so when connection failed or lost I need to 
    // end process like `std::process::abort()`
    // but I cant use it, because its unsafe

    let mut task_handler = vec![];

    // create some task

    join_all(task_handler).await;
  });
}
```

anyone have some ideas?

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? Is it failing to compile? Panicking? Something else?

Comment: Code work, but I need to safety shutdown this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call any of the `Runtime` shutdown methods [`shutdown_timeout`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.shutdown_timeout) or [`shutdown_background`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.shutdown_background).

If it is needed some king of waiting, you could spawn a task with a [`tokio::sync::oneshot`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html) that will trigger the shutdown when signaled.

```rust
use core::time::Duration;
use crate::tokio::time::sleep;
use tokio;

fn main() {
    let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap();
        
    let handle = rt.handle().clone();
    
    let (s, r) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel();
    
    rt.spawn(async move {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        s.send(0);
    });
    
    handle.block_on(async move {
        r.await;
        rt.shutdown_background();
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2965c95fccb98a856bec8d2652555568)

Comment: @Ruslan, it panics with what? in the docs examples they do exactly that. If not, use the oneshot channel approach instead.